# On windows, how do you verify the version number of CuDNN installed?

Tags: windows, cudnn

On windows, how do you verify the version number of CuDNN installed?

I'm finding a lot of results when I search for the answer for Linux machines. It doesn't seem like there's a clear way to find out what version is installed for Windows.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Go to C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include\

open cudnn.h

define CUDNN_MAJOR      5

define CUDNN_MINOR      1

define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 10

in my case its  5.1.10

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: On my machine cudnn header was installed in `C:\Program Files\cuDNN6\cuda\include`

Comment: In my case `cudnn.h` does not define the version numbers, but it rather imports them from `cudnn_version.h`, so I just had to open that file instead.

Comment: This is assuming that CuDNN files have been copied to this locatoin, but they could be anywhere on the system, and the location included in the system PATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

#cudnn version check (win10)

in my case its cuda 11.3v // u need to replace with ur verisons

```
more "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.3\include\cudnn_version.h"
```

output:
[image]

Comment: you should not replace anything here, but I +1 this because the path has changed since cuda 11 and now it is under cudnn_version

Answer (score -2):

In my case you should go in:
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2\include"

and later, open cudnn_version.h

in my case it shows:

#define CUDNN_MAJOR 8

#define CUDNN_MINOR 1

#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 0

finally, my version is: 8.1.0